# Проверка является ли строка числом

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QString`, нужно проверить является ли она числом.
В `QChar` есть метод `isNumber()`, который это делает, но в `QString` его нет. Думаю перебрать каждый символ, проверяя его, но может быть есть решение лучше.
Если таковое имеется, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: но ведь числа не только из цифр состоят…

Comment: А почему не использовать стандартные методы? Ну, например, использовать `strto...` или `sto..` и смотреть, осталось ли что-то несчитанным?

Comment: Потому, как понадобятся "лишние" преобразования `QString` в char*. А смысла в этом мало, т.к. QString сам все умеет)

Comment: @mymedia в моем случае это int

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg , для `int` - первый вариант в моем ответе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Читаем тут](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt):

`int QString::toInt(bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR, int base = 10) const`

[Для длинного целого](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLong):

`long QString::toLong(bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR, int base = 10) const`

Если просто проверить, что все символы в строке есть числа, или нужная "маска", то лучше [использовать регулярки](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#contains-4):

`bool QString::contains(const QRegExp &rx) const`

Comment: Дополню только, что для собственно проверки число ли эта строка используется параметр `bool *ok` для "подобных" функций (к указанным можно еще присовокупить `toDouble` и `toFloat`).